# Wrong output value in 8-bit ALU

Tags: verilog, modelsim, alu

I want to design an 8-bit ALU. I have written this code, but when I simulate it, the output has x value.  Why did it happen?

```
module eightBitAlu(clk, a, b,si,ci, opcode,outp);
input clk;
input [7:0] a, b;
input [2:0] opcode;
input si;
input ci;
output reg [7:0] outp;

always @(posedge clk)
begin

case (opcode)
3'b000: outp <= a - b;
3'b000 : outp <= a + b;
3'b001 : outp =0;
3'b010 : outp <= a & b;
3'b011 : outp <= a | b;
3'b100 : outp <= ~a;
endcase
end
endmodule
```

This is my test module:

```
module test_8bitAlu();

reg clk=0,a=3,b=1,si=0,ci=0,opcode=1;

eightBitAlu alu(clk, a, b,si,ci, opcode,outp);

initial begin
    #200 clk=1;
    #200 opcode=0;
    #200 opcode=2;
    #200 opcode=3;
    #200 opcode=4;
    #200;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are only 1 bit wide leaving the top 7 bits of your input ports un-driven.

```
reg clk=0,a=3,b=1,si=0,ci=0,opcode=1;
```

is equivalent to :

```
reg clk    = 0;
reg a      = 3;
reg b      = 1;
reg si     = 0;
reg ci     = 0;
reg opcode = 1;
```

What you need is:

```
reg        clk    = 0;
reg  [7:0] a      = 3;
reg  [7:0] b      = 1;
reg        si     = 0;
reg        ci     = 0;
reg  [2:0] opcode = 1;
wire [7:0] outp;
```

**Further improvemnets** would be to include the width on the integer assignment ie:

```
reg        clk    = 1'd0;
reg  [7:0] a      = 8'd3;
```

`b` for binary, `d` for decimal, `o` for octal and `h` for hexadecimal in `width'formatValue`

### Note

`outp` if not defined will be an implicit 1 bit wire.

Your clock in the testharness also only has 1 positive edge. You may prefer to define your clock as:

```
initial begin
  clk = 1'b0;
  forever begin
    #100 clk = ~clk;
  end
end
```

A complete version of the above is demonstrated at [EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/ZZ).

Comment: wow. that is right. but still I have problem, all of the bits of outp have 1'hz value except outp[0]. why this is happened?

Comment: I added this and I have 8 bit output but just bit outp[0] change.

Comment: I have just those code that I posted in my project. nothing else.